# Port assignmnt to processes

Tags: multithreading, networking, process, port, tcp

Can a process P1 running on machine on M1 create two(or more) connections with a process P2 running on machine M2 on two different ports? possible scenario could be in case of multi-threading. But I am not sure whether multiple threads of same process can run on separate port number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a process - or even a single thread - can use multiple connections, on multiple different ports, to the same remote machine.  The only restriction is that, between two machines - or technically, between two IP addresses - different connections must use a different port on at least one of the machines.  Thus, for example, the following connections can coexist:

```
IP Machine 1      Port     IP Machine 2      Port
123.456.789.111 : 1111  -  123.456.789.222 : 1111
123.456.789.111 : 1111  -  123.456.789.222 : 2222
123.456.789.111 : 2222  -  123.456.789.222 : 1111
```

(Specific IPs and ports for illustration purposes only; I don't know whether these ports are well known ports for any actual applications.)